# HTML - Cursors on a website

Tags: html, css, cursor, forum, phpbb

yes I KNOW and have read topics about how to make a cursor in HTML, and I know how to do that, but today i'm asking a bit of a different question. My question is how do I make a normal cursor on the website, like the regular pointing one, and when they hover over a link display ANOTHER cursor? For instance like on [this wikia](http://tdp4.wikia.com/wiki/Tdp4_Wiki), the image is green when pointing and RED when hovering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while hovering the particular content u can change the background image for cursor for exmaple

**css**

```
a:hover {
    cursor: url('http://img4.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20141101171405/tdp4/images/f/fd/JdHLHLi92.png'),pointer;
}

p:hover {
    cursor: url('http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20141101171352/tdp4/images/6/6d/DcoudoUO82.png'),text;
}
```

for refrence

https://plnkr.co/edit/Yj7CMxM7IbeoVoWeRtPF

Comment: Happy coding @SNiPEOO7

Answer (score 0):

Use this css property

```
cursor: url('image_url'),auto;
```

Please note that it most likely won't work on IE

Comment: I already found the answer thanks to gayathri, tweaked his suggestion a bit and it worked. Thanks for your contribution though :D

Comment: No problem, I did comment beforehand though :)